# Making fun of jinns make you kafir?

Tags: jinn

Hope you all are doing good.
I wanted to know that if we make fun of jinns like joking about them.

Does this makes one kafir?

Answer (score 1):

It’s just like any creation of Allah . Making fun of people or animals doesn’t make you unbeliever . It does make you unkind and maybe rude. Also when you are making fun of unseen . It’s like making fun of angels . Would there be any unseen results of your cruel behavior ? Only Allah knows but you should be careful how you address every creation .  All humans deserve kindness and well as all animals and every creation of Allah deserves respect.